# When typing into an empty Microsoft Word cell (table), the left border of the cell begins to move to the left, why?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have the following issue. When I want to write something into an empty cell in a table, the left border of the cell begins to move to the left, even trough I did not even reach the border of the cell. Could you tell me what could be the issue? Below please find a visualization of the issue (as you can see the cell extended by the amount of text I wrote into the cell, noting that the cell was initially completely empty).

[image: Example]

Comment: What are your table Alignment and Text Wrapping options set to?

Comment: Alignment is set to top left (the text alignment that is, if this is not what you are talking about please do direct me to the setting, so I can examine it). Also where can I find the text wrapping options?

Comment: Right-click in a table cell > Table Properties > Table tab.

Comment: The table was left aligned as soon as I changed it to right aligned the issue was resolved. Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're most welcome. I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click anywhere in the table and go to Table Properties. On the Table tab, check the alignment is set to Left and not Center or Right.

Comment: Just to add to this, having done some more testing, I had to make sure that the table alignment is right and that the text alignment is right (Some minutes later I had the same problem but caused because of text alignment and not the table alignment).